# The L2TP-VPN server did not respond - OS X Mountain Lion (happened after change of Router)

Tags: network, wifi, keychain, vpn, router

I used to be able to connect to [VPNgate's servers](http://www.vpngate.net/en/)

but ever since I changed to a new router (one of the new Netgear Nighthawks), it just stopped working.

I followed the [guide](http://www.vpngate.net/en/howto_l2tp.aspx#mac) on their site to setup the vpn connection, and it worked before. Now, it just gives me an error:

```
The L2TP-VPN server did not respond. Try reconnecting. If the problem
continues, verify your settings and contact your Administrator.
```

I tried the following:

- Rebooted computer many times
- Configured around with the keychain access (some people reported to have success once they allowed all applications to access vpn certificate)
- Looked around router settings but saw nothing special

I am using a Macbook Pro Retina 15 inch, and I am running OS X 10.8.2

Below is a log of what happens when I try to connect.

---

```
4/22/15 5:20:19.815 PM pppd[15702]: IPSec connection started
4/22/15 5:20:19.825 PM racoon[15703]: Connecting.
4/22/15 5:20:19.826 PM racoon[15703]: IPSec Phase1 started (Initiated by me).
4/22/15 5:20:19.826 PM racoon[15703]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Initiator, Main-Mode message 1).
4/22/15 5:20:22.828 PM racoon[15703]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Phase1 Retransmit).
4/22/15 5:20:25.527 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.apple.dynamic_pager[15704]) Exited with code: 1
4/22/15 5:20:25.527 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.apple.dynamic_pager) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
4/22/15 5:20:25.831 PM racoon[15703]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Phase1 Retransmit).
4/22/15 5:20:28.833 PM racoon[15703]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Phase1 Retransmit).
4/22/15 5:20:29.827 PM pppd[15702]: IPSec connection failed
```

Comment: Did you discover a solution?  I'm having the same problem.  Also, just curious, how do you produce the log?  I'm new to Macs. Thanks, Dave